# Helm: I need dependencies in charts/ but I only have templates/

Tags: python, templates, charts, kubernetes-helm

So I have this file structure (taken from https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/):

```
wordpress/
  Chart.yaml          # A YAML file containing information about the chart
  LICENSE             # OPTIONAL: A plain text file containing the license for the chart
  README.md           # OPTIONAL: A human-readable README file
  values.yaml         # The default configuration values for this chart
  values.schema.json  # OPTIONAL: A JSON Schema for imposing a structure on the values.yaml file
  charts/             # A directory containing any charts upon which this chart depends.
  crds/               # Custom Resource Definitions
  templates/          # A directory of templates that, when combined with values,
                      # will generate valid Kubernetes manifest files.
  templates/NOTES.txt # OPTIONAL: A plain text file containing short usage notes
```

I have only templates/ folder filled in with .yaml files. I want to use a library, [avionix](https://github.com/zbrookle/avionix), for Python that that requires dependencies in charts/ ([docs](https://github.com/zbrookle/avionix/blob/97e7c43741a3ebaa0620c0653cb660f892e1fd1f/docs/source/user_guide/using_external_helm_charts.rst)).

So my question is: How can I use my .yaml's from templates/ and use them as charts in charts/ that the library ([avionix](https://github.com/zbrookle/avionix)) is requiring, so that I can execute [this](https://github.com/zbrookle/avionix/blob/97e7c43741a3ebaa0620c0653cb660f892e1fd1f/examples/external_helm_charts_example.py) piece of code only from a local repo?

I am new to helm charts and avionix, sorry for this simple question :)

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking about how to set up the local repo from that snippet of the code?

Comment: do you want to generate a helm chart with this avionix library? or you want to extend a helm chart with a subchart?

Comment: Apparently I got confused. So my goal is to have either a local repo (like in the example in the question) or simply a link to a remote repo from where it will be pulled. So far I can see that the only way to use a chart (either local or remote) is to add it as a dependency. And this makes me confused, because my chart in templates/